# What's the best way to get a list of the contents of a specific group of DOM elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The basic scenario: I've got a series of elements on an HTML page, generated dynamically.  (Currently, they're all `divs`, but they don't need to be.)

What I want is a javascript function that will loop though all of those `divs` (or whatever) looking for the presence of a specific value.

What's the best, most cross-browser way to do this?  Does getElementsByName() work on `divs`  in all browsers?  Can I give them all the same ID and get an array back out of getElementById somehow?

If I change those `divs` to `spans` or `inputs`, does that make things easier?

Thanks!

(edit: it would be best, for this project, if there was a solution without using any external js libraries.  I assume jQuery has a function that does just this in one line, but for the moment I'd like to avoid opening that can of worms with the client.)

Comment: Where is the value on these divs? innerHTML? An attribute?

Comment: That's yet to be defined, quite frankly.  Whatever's easiest?

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName` is defined in DOM Core, so any browser which implements that works. That's about every browser in current use.

Take a gander over here for the specifics: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

One gotcha to be ware of, is that `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` - not an array. It works the same, but it is evaluated very late, so if you add/remove nodes to the DOM while traversing a `NodeList`, you will get weird results. In these cases, write two loops; First loop through the `NodeList` and store all entries in an array - Then loop through the array.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what the elements are, but what does matter is where they are in the page. If they are all child elements of a single parent element, your problem is simple. Give the parent element an ID and you can use `getElementById()` to grab it and iterate its children.

`getElementById()` behavior is undefined when more than one instance of an ID is found in the document. Most will return the first Element they can find, but you certainly can't cound on getting an array.

`getElementsByTagName()` will work only if you can use some obscure tag that you are sure won't appear elsewhere in your page. You could augment this by specifying that the elements you are interested in will have an attribute present that you can check for (such as @class or @title). You can then loop through the result of `getElementsByTagName()` checking for this and only look at Elements where the attribute is present.

Comment: Watch out for using .childNodes since different browsers will represent the HTML as different DOM structures. In particular, whitespace may or may not become TextNodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://jacksleight.com/blog/2008/01/14/getelementsby/) site to see what getElementBy most suites your needs.
There are some using libraries and some like **troelskn** wrote that apply for standard javascript in all supporting browsers.